# ComboBox Column Location

Tags: excel, vba

I have used the below script to allow the user to select a column from the ComboBox drop down.

How can i use the selected item to find the location of the column chosen by the user?

Imagine i wanted to set `Range("A1")` to be the second Cell from the user chosen column.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim LastCol As Long
Dim i As Long

'Define Final Column
LastCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column


ComboBox1.Text = "Please Select Column"
    
'Allows a list to be created based on Column names
For i = 1 To LastCol
    ComboBox1.AddItem Cells(1, i)
Next i

End Sub
```

The next part is where my code currently breaks down

```
Public Sub Continue_Click()

Dim A As Range

Set A = ComboBox1.Cells(2,1)
Range("A1") = A

Hide

End Sub
```

**EDIT**

I have used the following, unsure if this is the most efficient but seems to work.

`Set A = ActiveSheet.Rows("1:1").Find(Criteria1.ComboBox1.Value).EntireColumn`

I can then use `A.Cells`

Answer (score 0):

You could reference the LinkedCell of the ComboBox.